# Add math.js to Text Editor

Tags: javascript, math.js

I can't seem to add math.js to my editor using a CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="calc.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs@4.1.1/"></script>
</head>
```

I keep getting a MIME error in Chrome.

I also can't work out how to download it. When I click on the download link I just get a [page](https://unpkg.com/mathjs@4.1.1/dist/math.min.js) with all the code. Am I meant to copy this code over to a math.js file and save locally. Apologies this seems basic.

Comment: `src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs@4.1.1/dist/math.min.js"`?

Comment: It worked, but why and why not mine? Thanks anyway

Comment: You provided a path to a _directory_, not a (javascript) _file_. You're welcome.